# Realistic Hair - Creating Mess, Fringe, and Noise around Edges (Limiting Smoothness)

Tags: particles, hair, photorealism

I am trying to make realistic hair, but I have run into a roadblock. That being having separate strands of hair that don't follow the main flow of the hair.

Here is my current render:

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: you can do this with another layer of hair. Add another particle system or the [Frizz Hair modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/hair/deformation/frizz_hair_curves.html) for the Hair Curves system (Blender 3.5). It's also recommended to use references. It looks like you have attached the hair to the forehead, haven't you?